# Ignore text differences when comparing XML with xmlunit

Tags: java, xml, junit, xmlunit

I have a problem in comparing xml strings.

My compare function is

```
public static boolean compareXMLs(String xmlSource, String xmlCompareWith){

XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

XMLUnit.setNormalizeWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreDiffBetweenTextAndCDATA(true);

Diff myDiff = new Diff(xmlSource, xmlCompareWith);
myDiff.overrideDifferenceListener(new IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener());
return myDiff.similar();
}
```

My unit test is

```
 String xml1 = "<a>f</a>";
 String xml2 = "<a>1</a>";
 assertEquals(true, RestCommonUtility.compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));

 xml1 = "<a></a>";
 xml2 = "<a>1</a>";
 assertEquals(true, RestCommonUtility.compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));
```

My unit test passed in first assert, but fails in 2nd assert. I set [`IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener`](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.html) but still my 2nd assert fails. Is there any way to solve this problem.? Or is there any other framework could help in these kind of comparison?

Comment: try toString on the diff - from what i remember ignore just doesnt compare the text but acknowledges its there

Comment: Ya when I use new xmlunit it says, CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH is difference. It is different only. But I want to ignore that too.

Comment: Side note: use `assertTrue(foo)` rather than `assertEquals(true, foo)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own [`DifferenceListener`](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/api/index.html?org/custommonkey/xmlunit/DifferenceListener.html) that ignores a difference when one node has a single text child node and the other doesn't. Here is an example:

```
public class CompareStructureOnlyListener implements DifferenceListener {

  private IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener delegate =
      new IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener();

  @Override
  public int differenceFound(Difference difference) {
    int delegateResult = delegate.differenceFound(difference);

    if (delegateResult == DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE) {
      // Delegate thinks there is a difference, let's confirm

      if (difference.getId() == DifferenceConstants.HAS_CHILD_NODES_ID) {
        Node controlNode = difference.getControlNodeDetail().getNode();
        Node testNode = difference.getTestNodeDetail().getNode();

        Node nodeToTest = (controlNode.hasChildNodes()) ? controlNode : testNode;

        // If there is only a difference of one node and that node is a text
        // node, then ignore it
        if (nodeToTest.getChildNodes().getLength() == 1
            && nodeToTest.getFirstChild() instanceof Text) {
          return DifferenceListener.RETURN_IGNORE_DIFFERENCE_NODES_SIMILAR;
        } else {
          return DifferenceListener.RETURN_ACCEPT_DIFFERENCE;
        }
      }
    }  
    return delegateResult;
  }

  @Override
  public void skippedComparison(Node control, Node test) {
    // Does nothing
  }
}
```

And here are some tests which pass:

```
String xml1 = "<a>a</a>";
String xml2 = "<a>1</a>";
assertTrue(compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));

xml1 = "<a></a>";
xml2 = "<a>1</a>";
assertTrue(compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));

xml1 = "<a></a>";
xml2 = "<a><f></f></a>";
assertFalse(compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));
```

Side note: rename your `compareXMLs` method to something like `xmlsAreSimilar`, or something that easily indicates what the boolean return value means.

Comment: Ya I tried the same, it is working. But the below test fails.
     `xml1 = "<rt><a>f</a></rt>";
     xml2 = "<rt><a>1</a><b>ee</b></rt>";
     assertTrue(compareXMLs(xml1, xml2));`

Comment: @Pasupathi Isn't that what you want? I thought the only difference you wanted to ignore was when one element had text and the other didn't?

Comment: Actually I wanted is exactly your class name CompareStructureOnlyListener :) irrespective of the extra nodes or some of node not available.

Comment: @Pasupathi How is the listener supposed to know which structure differences it can ignore? Anyway, you can see from this answer how to approach the problem, you can tailor it to ignore whatever differences you see fit.

Comment: OK, I'll look into it. If any doubts, I'll post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the error reported is CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH then create a custom [IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/xmlunit/xmlunit/1.4/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.java#IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.0IGNORE_VALUEShttp://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/xmlunit/xmlunit/1.4/org/custommonkey/xmlunit/IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.java#IgnoreTextAndAttributeValuesDifferenceListener.0IGNORE_VALUES) which also ignores CHILD_NODELIST_LENGTH. Id run it through a debugger to confirm what the difference is then exclude it